# control margins with geometry or fullpage

Tags: margins, geometry

Is there a better way to set

```
\topmargin
-1.5cm
\textwidth
15.5cm
\textheight
23.5cm
\oddsidemargin
0.7cm
\evensidemargin
1.2cm
```

perhaps using `\usepackage{geometry}` or `\usepackage{fullpage}`?
What are the options to be invoked?

Comment: It is very easy - look at the documentation for `geometry` - it took me about 5 minutes to convert my manual margin controls to geometry options.

Comment: I can not recommend directly changing the margins via `\oddsidemargin` etc. Use the `geometry` package for example, say `\usepackage{geometry}[tmargin=1cm,bmargin=1.5cm,lmargin=1.5cm,rmargin=1.5cm,showframe=true]{geometry}` to set the margins and display a frame (for *debugging* use)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer yes, what I was asking is precisely a translation of the above in the geometry language, as far as it is possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is easily done, as @ChristianHupfer said, using the `geometry` package.

It has a nice way to set the margins while calling the `usepackage` directive. While a full answer, detailing all of the option is in the package manual, here is a shortcut *specific* for your answer. Since you provide `oddsidemargin` and `evensidemargin` I assume you have a twoside document.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[width=15.5cm,
            height=23.5cm,
            top=1.5cm,
            inner=0.7cm,
            outer=1.2cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}

 \end{document}
```

I used also `a4paper` as a documentclass option and the `showframe` package in order to show the frame for my example. Please double check that your margins are alright for whatever paper size you are using. Also, the geometry package has nice papersize options I invite you to checkout

[image]